# Where can I find which functions have been removed from PHP 5.4?

Tags: php

I'm working with a very old code base, and I need to know which functions have been removed in PHP 5.4 so that I can address them before upgrading. Can anybody tell me where I can find a list of functions that have been removed? I've looked at the Changelog, but it doesn't seem to list them. For example, I know that session_is_registered() has been removed, but I can't find any mention of it other than on documentation page for that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you SURE you looked at the changelog? http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.0

```
[[...snip...]]
Version 5.4.0
01-Mar-2012
...
 - Removed Legacy Features
     ....
     - session_is_registered(), ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find deprecated features here:

- http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.deprecated.php

Answer (score 0):

There is a script for that here http://www.typofree.org/article/archive/2011/may/title/check-your-php-code-for-deprecated-ini-directives-and-functions/

it's for PHP 5.3, but 5.3+ is easy to check manually or to simply add to the params of the script. It's designed for TYPO3 but it basically checks all scripts in a directory, so it shuold be usable for all kinds of web apps in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a list of depreciated functions for PHP.

Based off of the original PHP version you are converting from, you can go through each version of PHP up to the latest to ensure that all of your functions are valid for use.

You can find the depreciated functions for each PHP version on the official php.net site located here: http://www.php.net/manual/ by searching through their documentation.

To get a list of depreciated functions for PHP 5.4, for example, I would google `PHP 5.4 depreciated functions` and one of the top results should be from the official PHP documentation.

PHP 5.4 Depreciated Functions: http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php

It's also worth noting that they have a PHP migration guide, from migration from PHP 4 to PHP 5 here: http://www.php.net/migration5

Comment: I'm not looking for deprecated functions, I'm looking for the ones that have actually been removed completely.

Comment: Well good practice would be to treating depreciated functions as removed (as they will most likely be removed in the future).  Regardless, you can find the functions that are actually removed on the same pages mentioned above: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php